# embedding Google Maps in a JavaFX 2.2 desktop application throwing exception and generaly not performing

Tags: java, google-maps, webview, javafx-2

I have a project requiring the embedding of google maps in a desktop java application. I found after some research that Java FX does provide this functionality and proceeded to write a sample application as a PoC. the application worked and everything was fine.
After upgrading to the new 7u7 java version, my code no longer works like it did before. 
The code runs and displays the web page, but no gesture (paning/ zooming) events are fired to the web page (google maps) and for some reason when i clikc and drag (as if to pan) i get the enclosed exception which i can make no sense of.

I would very much appreciate any insight someone might have in the emmbedding of Google Maps in a JavaFX 2.2 application.
Thank you in advance for any help and/or suggestions

Following is my application code/HTML code and the exception thrown:

JavaFX code:

```
    private Scene scene;
    private MyBrowser myBrowser;
    private LocationClickHandler handler;
    private Vector<Button> buttons;
    //private Moderator moderator;



    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
    */
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      launch(args);
   }

    @Override
      public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

  buttons = new Vector<Button>();
  //moderator = new Moderator();
  handler=new LocationClickHandler();

  primaryStage.setTitle("java-buddy.blogspot.com");

  myBrowser = new MyBrowser();
  //moderator.registerAddIconListener(myBrowser);
  VBox mainbox = new VBox();
  mainbox.getChildren().add(myBrowser);



 // mainbox.getChildren().add(generateEntitiesButtonBox());
//  mainbox.getChildren().add(generateSensorsButtonBox());
  scene = new Scene(mainbox, 1280, 760);

  primaryStage.setScene(scene);

  primaryStage.show();

 }

    class MyBrowser extends Region {

  HBox toolbar;

  WebView webView = new WebView();
  WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();


  public MyBrowser(){
      webView.setMinSize(1280, 400);
      final URL urlGoogleMaps = getClass().getResource("googlemaps2.html");
      webEngine.load(urlGoogleMaps.toExternalForm());

      getChildren().add(webView);
      /*webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
              new ChangeListener<State>() {  
                @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, State oldState, State newState) {
                  if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                    JSObject win = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                    win.setMember("java", handler);
                  }
                }
              });*/




  }
```

HTML loaded into the Web View:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Java-Buddy: Google Maps</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <style>#mapcanvas { height: 500px; width: 100%}</style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var icon="icons/Tank.png";
    var last_clicked;
    var elliptical=0;

    var sensors = new Array();
    var sensors_to_targets = new Array();
    var targets = new Array();
    var target_paths = new Array();
    var target_polys = new Array();

    var counter =0;
    //var marker;

    function loadmap(){

      var options = {
          zoom: 16,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.507222, -0.1275),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
          streetViewControl: false
      }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"), options);
      google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize');  
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

        java.saveLocation(event.latLng.lat(),event.latLng.lng());


       });



      }





    </script>

    </head>
    <body onload="loadmap()">
    <div id="mapcanvas"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

exception thrown when dragging in the web view:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Clipboard.putContent: null data
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumClipboard.putContent(QuantumClipboard.java:442)
at javafx.scene.input.Clipboard.setContent(Clipboard.java:226)
at com.sun.webpane.sg.UIClientImpl.confirmStartDrag(UIClientImpl.java:178)
at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.confirmStartDrag(WebPage.java:861)
at javafx.scene.web.WebView$19.handle(WebView.java:1204)
at javafx.scene.web.WebView$19.handle(WebView.java:1201)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.fireEvent(Scene.java:2627)
at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.process(Scene.java:2706)
at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.access$8700(Scene.java:2603)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3340)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3164)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3119)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1559)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2261)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:228)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:528)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:922)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the issue Sergey linked, it seems one part of this issue is caused by an error in [Google Maps v3 api](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4238) and is a result of enabling touch events in the browser (panning doesn't work with Google Maps v3 api in Chrome with touch events enabled either).

JavaFX 2.0.x (and 2.1.x) webview did not have touch events implemented, but JavaFX 2.2 does, hence one reason for the difference in behaviour between the two.

As a work around you could use [v2 of the google maps api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference) which don't feature this bug (well at least until that version of the api goes offline on May 19, 2013).  Or you can use JavaFX 2.1 until the JavaFX team and Google implement a fix/workaround.  Or you can continue seeking other workarounds such as that suggested by Sergey or variation thereof which works for you.

Comment: the best thing to do will be to revert back to JavaFX 2.1. As i stated earlier i tried reverting back to 2.0.3 (which is the latest old version oracle provides on their site) and the interface with Google Maps worked fine, but the JavaScript to JavaFX bridge is not implemented on that version and i require that feature as well. the only version that will work with Google Maps and implements a JavaScript-JavaFX bridge is 2.1 , and i cant find anywhere to download it from. I need the 2.1 32 version. If you know of somewhere i can download it from it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry the JavaFX 2.1 runtime and sdk is currently [not where it's supposed to be](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javafx-419431.html), so I don't know where to find them.

Comment: Oracle have now placed the [JavaFX 2.1 runtime and sdk](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javafx-419431.html) where they are supposed to be.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone. I found that i could get JavaFX 2.1 by downloading and installing Java SE 7u5 which comes bundled with 2.1. but now i see that Oracle has put 2.1 where it is supposed to be. thank you again.

Comment: @jewelsea Hi, I'm from two years later. This piece of crap still doesn't work with JavaFX 2.2 + GoogleMaps v3, and I really don't wanna downgrade. Are there any other workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug in WebView, I'll file it.

As a workaround you can provide an empty drag handler to your WebView:

```
        webView.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                // intentionally do nothing
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yes, I could do that. But i need the functionality of the underlying google maps. i need the drag event to be relayed to the web page to enable paning. I dint thinki mentioned it but no events seem to be relayed to the web page (no click, except on the buttons. no mouce scroll and no drag).

Comment: UPDATE: I reverted back to JavaFX 2.0.3 and referenced the jfxrt.jar from there. seems everything is working fine on that version. getting panning and scrolling and no exceptions thrown.