# JavaFX / Howto embed map in SplitPane

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

today's question is about embedding a map view into a JavaFX application. I basically followed the instructions on [StackOverFlow - embedding google map in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391508/embedding-google-maps-in-a-javafx-2-2-desktop-application-throwing-exception-and) and [Embed OpenLayers with OpenStreetMap](http://java-buddy.blogspot.de/2012/05/embed-openlayers-with-openstreetmap-in.html), so everything like the `*.html` file is in place. But there, people are adding the `WebView` to main `Scene`. For me, I would like to add the `WebView` to a `SplitPane`. ThereFore I prepared the `application.fxml` file as followed:

```
<SplitPane id="SplitPane" dividerPositions="0.5" orientation="HORIZONTAL" prefHeight="260.0" prefWidth="850.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
    <items>
        <TableView id="tableView1" fx:id="table" prefHeight="263.0" prefWidth="433.0">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn text="one" /><TableColumn text="two" /><TableColumn text="three" />
            </columns>
        </TableView>
        <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
            <children>
                <Region fx:id="webViewRegion" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            </children>
        </AnchorPane>
     </items>
</SplitPane>
```

The FXML file is loaded by the `FXMLLoader` when the application is started. In the application controller I get the `Region` as followed:

```
@FXML
private Region webViewRegion;

class MyMapView extends Region {

    HBox toolbar;
    WebView webview = new WebView();
    WebEngine webEngine = webview.getEngine();

    public MyMapView() {
        final URL urlGoogleMaps = getClass().getResource("openstreetmap.html");
        webEngine.load(urlGoogleMaps.toExternalForm());
        getChildren().add(webview);
    }
}

private void load_webView() {
    webViewRegion = new MyMapView();
}
```

For me, now I do not exactly know how to populate the `Region` with the `Webview` in a correct way or if there is any better approach?