# SWT Browser navigator version

Tags: java, windows, internet-explorer, browser, swt

Even if my Windows has the latest version of IE, the [SWT Browser](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/Browser.html) still runs on version **5.0** (yes, FIVE). At least that's what a simple `alert(navigator.appVersion)` says so.

- `System.setProperty("org.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion", "8000");` does not work
- `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion 8000` does not work
- I don't necessarily need v10.0 to work, but at least a DECENT version
- `SWT.MOZILLA` and `SWT.WEBKIT` are out of the question. XULRunner gives headaches

*SWT v3.8.1*

**Edit:**

Actually, now that I think about it...

```
5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; Trident/6.0; MDDRJS)
//                    ^ is this the browser version? Because the HTML and CSS
//                      functionalities beg to differ.
```

Comment: Which version of SWT are you using?

Comment: @Baz Version `3.8.1`. Too outdated?

Comment: Can you check if the problem persists even if you use the newest version (4.3)?

Comment: @Baz Still the same. `5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; Trident/6.0; MDDRJS)`.

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might be relevant

Comment: @Baz Good. So now I know my navigator version inside the SWT `Browser` is IE 10. But why does the content (i.e. HTML + CSS) differ from the desktop browser? Example: `padding` and `margin` of a `hr` aren't recognized.

Comment: No idea, SWT Browser is a b*tch... Sorry, I can't really help here.

Comment: @Baz Oh, btw, what browser component are you using in JaRSS for showing 'real webpage'? :-)

Comment: I see someone did some research :D It's a simple SWT `Browser` using `SWT.NONE` as style bits, why?

Comment: @Baz Well for example, the webpage for StackOverflow questions works great. All the HTML and JavaScript stuff. Or maybe this site is reaaaaaaaaally well optimized for ancient versions of IE ...

Comment: You can try the [IETester](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) and see if Stackoverflow works with older versions of IE.

Comment: @Baz Now I'm sad because it works. This means I have to make IE optimizations for the SWT `Browser`. Damn it.

Comment: You **could** try using a Swing browser like [this one](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html) with the SWT/AWT bridge... However, be prepared to face some problems on the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Java 8 is around the corner, and the SWT `Browser` is a pain in the ... elbow, I do recommend JavaFX to anyone that reads this.

The JavaFX `WebEngine` is delightful, and you can embed it in a SWT `Composite` using the `FXCanvas` class from JavaFX.

If you're still using JavaFX 2.2, beware of [some sneaky bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391508/embedding-google-maps-in-a-javafx-2-2-desktop-application-throwing-exception-and).

Cheers.

Comment: Good answer swt browser is giving me a headache

Answer (score 2):

change this registry entry `"java.exe"` under
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` to `"8000"`

Comment: I am really happy to say that this solution worked for me. I think the whole SWT Browser seems to be plagued with such compatibility problems. At least now I have a solution/workaround to this problem.