# Java desktop application with google maps

Tags: java, google-maps, netbeans, desktop-application, jxmapkit

I need help with these, I am currently developing an a desktop aplication in java with netbeans IDE.
One requirement of the app is that must have a map on it.
I was serching and i find these: https://today.java.net/article/2007/10/24/building-maps-your-swing-application-jxmapviewer.
But i try to downoad the JXMaptKit or the JXMapViewer but i dnd't found it.

Can anyone knows a workaround of that problem or an example that i can use?

Thanks!

PD. the app that i'm currently developing is for academic purposes.

Comment: It appears to be part of Swing-Labs, you could try downloading it using maven

Comment: You could also take a look at https://java.net/downloads/swingx/releases/

Comment: I think they have stopped swing-labs and it's not available anymore. Though, I had to find through my old machine. I have uploaded the version of swing-x jar here http://www.filetolink.com/5a1cb74565

You can download it and see if this helps you. Thanks

Comment: Mr. 777, thanks for the file, but, the jar dont have the classes that i need: https://today.java.net/images/2007/10/find_jxmapkit.png

Comment: i open the libery on netbeans

Comment: @Mr.777 While it's troublesome to download, it's still there, no one seems to have bothered to move it since Java.net migration.  I think they prefer to distribute via Maven know.  Check the links from my previous comments, the libraries are there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at a modern JavaFX 2 framework which uses Webkit-based `WebEngine` to render a webpage. Here is a Google Maps demo: http://fxexperience.com/2011/05/maps-in-javafx-2-0/?

Comment: thanks for a quick reply, i was looking but that demo don't work for me do you know other way to do it?

Comment: This demo is of '11 and may be outdated, it was working for me two years ago. The general approach in this demo is to embed a webbrowser widget into a JavaFX app, bind it in Java and utilize Google Maps api by invoking JS from java. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391508/embedding-google-maps-in-a-javafx-2-2-desktop-application-throwing-exception-and or a [google query](https://www.google.ru/search?q=javafx+google+maps&oq=javafx+google+maps&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l5.8931j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) might be helpful.

Comment: Andrey, as i see in the post there are a few error that are not solved, see the last coment. now im trying to work with the code example that is in the page.

Comment: when i run the app i get a EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION I download the javaFX from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/202fxdownload-1521662.html

Comment: also i put a library on the proyect with the jfxrt.jar

Comment: i get this error Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

Comment: There is no need to install JavaFX manually. Just update you JDK to the latest and you would have it bundled. Installing it manually would definitely lead to errors.