# Java desktop application with interactive Google maps

Tags: java, swing, google-maps, desktop-application

I am trying to build a desktop app using java with google maps services api. The app should be able to use the google maps direction service.

I have been reading and trying out the API reference of google map services that can be found here http://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-java/v0.1.10/javadoc/. Is there any way to actually display the map direction obtained from DirectionsApiRequest function?

Regards,
Wayne

Comment: Have you tried reading this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962366/java-desktop-application-with-google-maps or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19701105/embed-google-maps-in-java-desktop-application

Comment: Yes i did, but our assignment require us to utilize the Google API and not utilizing any other third party libraries.